# Proving two inequalities that are used in the proof of Brun's theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, twin-primes

So I was reading a proof of [Brun's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%27s_theorem) in [AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Brun%27s_constant), then I came to these two inequalities that I can not figure out how they have been obtained.

It states that if $p$ stands for prime numbers in the expressions below and $y\in\mathbb{N}$ then there exists a contant $C\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\prod_{p\le y}(1-\frac{1}{p})\le \frac{C}{(\ln y)^2}$$
Also
$$\sum_{p\le y}\frac{1}{p}\le e\ln\ln y$$
The only fact I thought might be helpful to prove them was [Prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) but I was not able to find the way out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: These are two of Mertens' theorems. (third and second)

Comment: @Mastrem Thank you, sir!

Comment: It should be noted that the inequality $$\prod_{p \leq y}(1-p^{-1}) \leq C (\log y)^{-2}$$ does not hold for $y$ arbitrarily large. Again, see Mertens' theorems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens'_theorems).